# How to show a modal on the "same level" as the clicked button

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue. I use a boostrap modal with a form in it. I use it to make changes in a list.
My problem is that if I open the modal at the bottom of the page, this one opens at  the top. If I have to make several changes in my list, I have to go down, open, save, and go down again... How could I do if I want that my modal opend next to the clicked button ? So I won't have to scroll so much.

Thanks in advance,
Matthieu526

Comment: can you show a small snippet of code illustrating the problem? Or a jsFiddle or something? Hard to say what the problem is otherwise.

Comment: Please provide us code

Answer (score 1):

In some frameworks like Primefaces there's a component called "Overlay" that shows a pop-up window next to the element that has invoked the component.

I guess this component was created from jQuery-UI basic code (or maybe a plugin), so if you can use jQuery in your form you can probably use this component/plugin.

Overlay is usually a fixed panel that is rendered at the middle of the page.

You may have another problem: if you are refreshing the page under the pop-up, the browser will take you again to the top. You should refresh your list with ajax or an ajax-built component (again like primefaces, ZK, or some other frameworks do).